# Managing Per User Data with SQL Azure

Tags: azure, azure-sql-database

I am developing an app which stores collections of user generated data in the cloud on a per user basis. I am having trouble deciding the based way to handle end user silo'ing .

What is the best way to store a collection of data per end user in such a way that it is only accessed by a set of user specified credentials.

As the collection can have it's entities modified by a phone client I would like to be concious of sending the hold collection back and forth over the wire on each update.

I am using .net for development

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please introduce authentication. For example, we can use ASP.NET membership: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yh26yfzy.aspx. It helps us to authenticate users. We can store ASP.NET membership data in a SQL Azure database. We can also use ASP.NET membership in a Windows Phone application. Please refer to http://www.kotancode.com/2010/08/06/aspnet-authentication-wp7/ for detailed information.

Best Regards,

Ming Xu.

Answer (score 1):

You could think of SQL Azure storage or blob containers. You can make private containers allowed only to you and the Signed Identifiers you choose, your end user.

Regards,

Miquel